# How can I configure autoscaling in Azure App service based on load

Tags: azure, scaling, autoscaling, horizontal-scrolling, azure-appservice

I have configured app service autoscaling on CPU and memory utilisation. However I have observed the CPU never shooting up. So I was wondering if there was a way to auto scale based on load in appservice?Any input much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**You can define autoscale properties based on some predefined rules & schedules**.

If your load is increasing which means CPU utilization is more, then **SCALING OUT** is good when your load is more for specific time period and it automatically balances when load is normal.

You can find the list of resources for which **Autoscale** property is enabled or not in the **Azure Monitor** > **AutoScale** Menu.

For setting up the **autoscaling** based on load and knowing more information, you can refer to this MSFT [Doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/autoscale/autoscale-get-started) and [Doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-environment-auto-scale)